# Function objects in Smalltalk (or executing blocks with no `value:`)

Tags: functional-programming, smalltalk, squeak, pharo

Is it possible to send an anonymous message to an object? I want to compose three objects like this (think FP):

```
 " find inner product "
 reduce + (applyToAll * (transpose #(1 2 3) #(4 5 6)))
```

where `reduce`, `applyToAll` and `transpose` are objects and `+`, `*` and the two arrays are arguments passed to anonymous messages sent to those objects. Is it possible to achieve the same using blocks? (but no explicit usage of `value:`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps what you really want to do is define a DSL inside Smalltalk?

> [With HELVETIA we explore a lightweight approach to embed new languages into the host language. The approach reuses the existing toolchain of editor, parser, compiler and debugger by leveraging the abstract syntax tree (AST) of the host environment. Different languages cleanly blend into each other and into existing code.](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/helvetia)

Comment: but while you might want to do it, and can, perhaps you shouldn't. At least not to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
aRealObject reduceMethod: +; 
            applyToAll: *; 
            transpose: #(#(1 2 3) #(4 5 6));
            evaluate
```

would work when aRealObject has defined the right methods. Where do you need a block?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `doesNotUnderstand:`. If `reduce` is an object that does not implement `+` but you send it anyway, then instead its `doesNotUnderstand:` method will be invoked. Normally it just raises an error. But you can override the default, and access the selector `+` and the other argument and do whatever you like with them.

For simplicity, create a class `Reduce`. On its class side, define the method:

```
doesNotUnderstand: aMessage
    ^aMessage argument reduce: aMessage selector
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Reduce + (#(1 2 3) * #(4 5 6))
```

which in a Squeak workspace answers 32, as expected.

It works because `*` is already implemented for Collections with suitable semantics.

Alternatively, add a class `ApplyToAll` with this class-side method:

```
doesNotUnderstand: aMessage
    ^aMessage argument collect: [:e | e reduce: aMessage selector]
```

and also add this method to `SequenceableCollection`:

```
transposed
    ^self first withIndexCollect: [:c :i | self collect: [:r | r at: i]]
```

Then you can write

```
Reduce + (ApplyToAll * #((1 2 3) #(4 5 6)) transposed)
```

which is pretty close to your original idea.